# How do I 'reset' a React component after a Mutation error with react-apollo?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client

I'm learning Apollo Server and Apollo Client and following some online examples. One paradigm I've seen is for apollo-react mutations to do something like this following

```
render() {
    const {props: {history}} = this
    const {state: {username, password}} = this

    return <Mutation mutation={REGISTER}
                     onCompleted={() => history.push('/login')}>
      {(register, {data, error, loading}) => {
        if (error) {
          return <div>{error.toString()}</div>
        }
        if (loading) return <div>Loading...</div>
        return ({JSX form, etc})
```

It works fine, and when I get an error -- in my case with a duplicate registration, for example -- I get the error message displayed instead of the normal JSX.  I'm stumped what to do then to 'reset' the page.  That is, I'd like to be able to take some action which would 'clear' the Mutation's error and have it go back to rendering the JSX as it did before the error arrived (either the user could take the action or I'd time the error out and then 'reset' the page).  If I refresh the page it works fine, but obviously I don't want to have to do that!

I've done some searching and immediately I find myself deep in discussions of the Apollo Client Cache, which is next on my list to learn.  For the moment, I'm wondering whether there is a simpler way to do what I'm trying to do.

Any clues much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest solution might be to use the React component's state to hold the error returned from the mutation. And then provide the user action to clear it.

Expanding on you example, it might look something like this:

```
render() {
    const {props: {history}} = this
    const {state: {username, password, registrationError}} = this

    if (registrationError) {
      return (
        <div>
          {registrationError.toString()}
          <button onClick={() => this.setState({registrationError: null})}>
            Clear Error
          </button>
        </div>
      );
    }

    return <Mutation mutation={REGISTER}
                     onCompleted={() => history.push('/login')}
                     onError={(error) => this.setState({registrationError: error})}>
      {(register, {data, error, loading}) => {
        if (error) {
          // Just in case this is hit, return null
          return null;
        }
        if (loading) return <div>Loading...</div>
        return ({JSX form, etc})
```

Notice the error rendering was moved out of the `Mutation` callback.
I'm not entirely sure

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if the error will clear on rerender of `Mutation`, so I used the `onError` prop and return null just in case.